# Am i using the GMFBridge.DLL and GMFBridge player correctly and can gmf player be made to take data from socket?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, directshow

I require an application in which i want to give the byte stream of NAL units to  GMFBridge player instead of file.so i did the following
for demo
Takes the file and parse the file so that i can i find the nal unit

```
   FILE* infile;

    uint8_t* buf = (uint8_t*)malloc(BUFSIZE );
    char* buf1 = new char(BUFSIZE );

    h264_stream_t* h = h264_new();

    /*if (argc < 2) { usage(); return EXIT_FAILURE; }*/
     infile = fopen(Filepath, "rb");
   while (1)
    {
        rsz = fread(buf + sz, 1, BUFSIZE - sz, infile);

    fseek (infile , 0 , SEEK_END);
   lSize = ftell (infile);
   rewind (infile);
   buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
  if (buffer == NULL)
  {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,infile);
  if (result != lSize) 
  {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}
   fprintf( h264_dbgfile1,"data in file is %lld\n",buffer);
   int l=strlen(buffer);
      fclose (h264_dbgfile1);
  if (rsz == 0)
        {
            if (ferror(infile)) { fprintf( stderr, "!! Error: read failed: %s \n", strerror(errno)); break; }
            break;  // if (feof(infile)) 
        }

        sz += rsz;

        while (find_nal_unit(p, sz, &nal_start, &nal_end) > 0)
{
                   int length =nal_end-nal_start;
            int j=0;
            while(length!=0)
            {

            for (int start=nal_start;start<=nal_end;start++)
            {
                             FileData[pointer][j]=buffer[start];
                //FileData[pointer][j]=(p[j]);
                j++;
                length--;
                if(length==0)
                    break;
            }
            }

HRESULT hr = m_pPlayer->AddClip(ofn.lpstrFile, &pClip);//i am not able to give the data here
```

Please tell the above solution or can we connect the GMFBridge player to take data from socket and play it continuously.
I tried for socket but i didn't recv the data as connect call was suceessfull

```
int find_nal_unit(uint8_t* buf, int size, int* nal_start, int* nal_end)
{
    int i;
    // find start
    *nal_start = 0;
    *nal_end = 0;

    i = 0;
    while (   //( next_bits( 24 ) != 0x000001 && next_bits( 32 ) != 0x00000001 )
        (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0x01) && 
        (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0 || buf[i+3] != 0x01) 
        )
    {
        i++; // skip leading zero
        if (i+4 >= size) { return 0; } // did not find nal start
    }

    if  (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0x01) // ( next_bits( 24 ) != 0x000001 )
    {
        i++;
    }

    if  (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0x01) { /* error, should never happen */ return 0; }
    i+= 3;
    *nal_start = i;

    while (   //( next_bits( 24 ) != 0x000000 && next_bits( 24 ) != 0x000001 )
        (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0) && 
        (buf[i] != 0 || buf[i+1] != 0 || buf[i+2] != 0x01) 
        )
    {
        i++;
        // FIXME the next line fails when reading a nal that ends exactly at the end of the data
        if (i+3 >= size) { *nal_end = size; return -1; } // did not find nal end, stream ended first
    }

    *nal_end = i;
    return (*nal_end - *nal_start);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bridge is connecting two graphs so that you could change their states independently without unnecessary streaming breaks. It has nothing to do with H.264, Sockets, and NAL Units.

If you find or create a filter which can deliver payload received from socket into DirectShow pipeline, the bridge will be able to accept it and deliver into the second graph.

Comment: thanks for the reply sir can you please five me the indication in which file and where i have to edit as i don't have much experience with direct show...willbe very thank ful to you

Comment: Ask a great question and be sure to get help with it. So far you copy/pasted a fragment of code and posted an unrelated question.

Comment: ohk but please tell how to give the individual nal unit to gmf player and make it play continously

Comment: sir i downloaded a RTSP source filter from the link http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtspdirectshow/?source=dlp its again not building and its a library can you please tell me how to use it

Comment: Don't spam like this. This is totally unrelated. Learn how to write great questions, make sure to read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).